removing reversed vector items from a list
Suppose I have a list of vectors in R each of item being of differing length. How do I find and remove items that have a duplicate but for which that duplicate is the reverse of the one of the list's containing vectors?
I've tried looping by doing pairwise comparisons but is there a quicker way with a shorter assignment expression? perhaps a filter on the list?

better provide an example and expected output

item1 = 1 2 3, item2 = 3 2 1, item3 = 4 5 7, output: 1 2 3, 4 5 7. i just want to remove the "duplicated" reversed vectors from the list. the list could be say 10 items and the vectors of any length, there could be more than 1 "duplicate" for any item.

Update
If you want to remove the reversed duplicates only, you
f <- function(lst) {
    for (i in seq_along(lst)) {
        idx <- lst %in% list(rev(lst[[i]]))
        if (length(idx) > 0) {
            lst[idx] <- NA
        }
    }
    Filter(Negate(anyNA), lst)
}

which gives, for example
> f(lst)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 5 4

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

Data Example
> (lst <- list(c(1, 2, 3), c(5, 4), c(3, 2, 1), c(4, 5), c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5)))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 5 4

[[3]]
[1] 3 2 1

[[4]]
[1] 4 5

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[6]]
[1] 4 5


Previous
With your specific example in your question, you can simply use
> lst[!duplicated(lapply(lst, sort))]
$item1
[1] 1 2 3

$item3
[1] 4 5 7

Data Example
lst <- list(item1 = c(1, 2, 3), item2 = c(3, 2, 1), item3 = c(4, 5, 7))


this worked! r is so compact sometimes. thanks so much.

This is nice given the example - but what if you have a list(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3), c(3,2,1))? Is the second element supposed to be removed given it's not a reverse duplicate of any previous element? I really don't know.

@SamR aha, that is a good and interesting question, let me think about it :D

@SamR I have updated my answer with another implementation, hope it works in general cases.

@ThomasIsCoding - nice. At times like this I wish SO allowed one super-upvote a day :)
